# Optimize or ditch LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

So I have a LINQ (to SQL) query that pulls information from a database into a grid.  There is a function to aggregate the grid data based on the current filter parameters which will sum the amount of recurring "X"'s in the grid data.

For instance, lets assume the grid displays customer vists to a grocery store.  The original data may show the follow:

```
Date     | Name       | No. Prod   | Total $
--------------------------------------------
01/02/13 | Customer A | 4 products | $23.00 
01/02/13 | Customer B | 2 products | $3.26
01/02/13 | Customer C | 7 products | $47.42
01/16/13 | Customer A | 3 products | $26.22
```

Clicking the summation function for the clients column will display the following grid data:

```
Cnt| Name       | Tot. Prod  | Total $  
--------------------------------------
2  | Customer A | 7 products | $49.22 
1  | Customer B | 2 products | $3.26
1  | Customer C | 7 products | $47.42
```

My problem is that I am doing the summation logic in a LINQ query.  I assumed this would be fast...but it is just the opposite.  Here is a sample.

```
Expression<Func<OrdersView, bool>> filter;
filter = m => m.RecordCreated >= fromDate && m.RecordCreated <= toDate && m.DepartmentID == _depID;

var ClientAggOrders = dataContext.OrdersView
    .Where(filter)
    .GroupBy(m => m.Name)
    .Select(gr => new
        {
            Name = gr.Key,
            Count = gr.Where(s => s.ID != null).Count(),
            id = gr.Select(s => s.ID),
            S1 = gr.Sum(s => s.Tare < s.Gross ? s.Tare : s.Gross),
            S2 = gr.Sum(s => s.Tare < s.Gross ? s.Gross : s.Tare),
            NetWeight = gr.Sum(s => s.NetWeight),
            Price = gr.Sum(s => s.NetPrice)
        }
    ).ToList();
```

My question is, why is this such bad practice?  LINQ allows for these expressions in the SELECT clause, but the time it takes to execute is beyond absurd to the point where I don't see it being beneficial in any real world scenario.

Am I using LINQ wrong and should I just move my logic outside of the query or can this be optimized and done within LINQ properly?  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is this `LINQ to SQL`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: You need to examine the SQL that Linq is generating and sending to SQL to evaluate. With all the grouping and sum's I would guess that the SQL is horrific.

Comment: This line looks suspect: `id = gr.Select(s => s.ID),` - if you are grouping by Name, why are you trying extract a single ID within the group?

Comment: @PinnyM The client-side grid demands a unique ID as a reference.

Comment: @Jason With an ORM the SQL is almost **always** horrific. The parser and optimizer generally don't care, though, and rarely does it have an effect on performance. Rarely...

Comment: It's probably better to group by `OrdersView.CustomerId` or something. Instead of grouping by name... Unless the same customer can have multiple accounts... Then take `gr.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name)`

Comment: I'd really be interested in seeing the generated sql for this. Additionally, when you say slow how slow do you really mean? Is it take 10 seconds, a minute?

Comment: What is the performance if you enter the SQL directly, for example in the SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @LéMuffinMan depends on the number of records.  ~100 takes less than a second.  ~1000 takes 10-15 sec.  ~5000 is several minutes, haven't let that finish yet.  Exponential degredation.  I'm trying to get the generated SQL but am having some problems for some reason.  Will post ASAP.

Comment: Can you try this without the lines `Count = gr.Where(s => s.ID != null).Count()`, and `id = gr.Select(s => s.ID),` ? The latter appears to be selecting all ids in the group. If this is always the same id, then you can move that to the GroupBy, or replace it with something like `gr.Max(s=>s.ID)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQPad to see the SQL that is generated.

Because of the way LINQ to SQL works, `id = gr.Select(s => s.ID)` causes a subquery to be executed for every group. Remove this, and instead get the ID+Name in your GroupBy: `.GroupBy(m => new{m.ID, m.Name})`

You should find that the generated SQL will now be a single statement, instead of the main statement plus a statement for each group.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  I had a feeling this was a relatively simple issue...you learn something new everyday! The performance gain is like night and day....you're a life saver Edward!  ...and now that I think about it, I can't believe I didn't find the Select() subquery suspect.  LINQ makes me do some really stupid stuff >.<, I do love it when I get it right though!

Answer (score 0):

Perform grouping only in memory? Solve your problem?

```
var ordersView = 
    dataContext.OrdersView
    .Where(m => m.RecordCreated >= fromDate && m.RecordCreated <= toDate && m.DepartmentID == _depID)
    .ToList(); 

var ClientAggOrders = ordersView.GroupBy(m => m.Name).Select(gr => new
{
    Name = gr.Key,
    Count = gr.Where(s => s.ID != null).Count(),
    id = gr.Select(s => s.ID),
    S1 = gr.Sum(s => s.Tare < s.Gross ? s.Tare : s.Gross),
    S2 = gr.Sum(s => s.Tare < s.Gross ? s.Gross : s.Tare),
    NetWeight = gr.Sum(s => s.NetWeight),
    Price = gr.Sum(s => s.NetPrice)
}).ToList();
```